# Guest id and user id in Magento

Tags: magento, session, userid

Is the user id value is same as guest id value after a guest has been place an order that means logged in?

```
$customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$vistitorId = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getVisitorId();
```

Please make me knock if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. CustomerId is totally different from the visitorid. Magento Create Visitorid per session. But Customerid is created when user get registered.